# Selenium, C#, neither Chrome nor Firefox launch the automated scrip, but IE does (added script)

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am running the below script in Visual Studio as a test project.  The issues that I am experiencing is that Chrome does not run the script because it times out.  The same behavior is experienced using Firefox; however, the script runs successfully in Internet Explorer.  Can anyone assist if they have experienced this problem? I have updated to the latest webdrivers, updated to the latest version of V.S., even uninstalled and re-install VS, but I have not had the best of luck. Chrome and Firefox browser opens, but they remain idle and eventually I get a time out message. I noticed that it keeps the chromedriver and the geckodriver running in the task manager, and I have to endthose sessions manually.

`Visual Studio Pro 2017 Ver 15.8.7
.net Framework ver  4.7.02046
Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver ver 0.22.0
Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver ver 2.43.0
Selenium.WebDriver.IEDriver ver 3.141.0`

Message: Initialization method {{ProjectName}} threw exception. OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:xxxx/session timed out after 60 seconds. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The operation has timed out.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace ChromeFF_Fix
{
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        //IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Users\martigi\Downloads");
        //IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(@"C:\Users\martigi\Downloads");
        //IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        //IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://google.com");
        driver.Quit();
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem with Firefox (I don't use Chrome for testing). 
When I tried debugging it, I've noticed that it code newer reaches the line after calling FirefoxDriver constructor.

The solution for me was to download the latest Gecko driver, which is currently v0.23.0 - https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.23.0.